# How to change 5 minute interval data to hourly interval

Tags: python, excel, csv, data-transform, exploratory-data-analysis

So I have data of the temperature recorded on a thermostat every 5 minutes. I would like to change the data so that the file has only the data recorded every hour. I know there is a way to group the data but I don't want the sum/min/max/avg etc. I want the temperature for each hour. Let me know if this makes sense and if you need anything else.
[The data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXR9d.png)

Comment: It would make things even easier for us if you could post a sample of your csv data somewhere we can download it and test out the solution

Comment: Please post your attempt at solving the problem. You have 5 minute data. How do you want that converted to hourly? Pick the middle one? Take an average for the hour?

Comment: Where can I post my csv file? In terms of how I want to convert it to hourly, I want the last value which would be of the next hour so 1:00 - 2:00 should pick 2:00 and ignore the 5-minute increments in between.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way with python would be with the pandas package. If you don't have it:

```
pip install pandas
```

Then in your script import it and use it to filter out all date values in the first column that are not on the hour. Let me know if this works for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
df1 = df[df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%M:%S').eq('00:00')].copy()
print(df1)
df1.to_csv(index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with using some randomly generated data.  I just filtered the data frame to where the Series.dt.minute attribute equals 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

test_list = []

date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-05-26', '%Y-%m-%d')
for i in range(30):
    date_time += datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    new_row = {'datetime': date_time, 'temp': rng.integers(low=30, high=95, size=1)[0]}
    test_list.append(new_row)

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_list)
hourly_df = test_df[test_df['datetime'].dt.minute == 0]
```